# Configuring SQL Server to Oracle initial data load in Goldengate

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle12c, data-migration, oracle-golden-gate

As per my understanding before setting up transaction replication in Oracle Goldengate, we have to setup initial data load. In my case the source is SQL Server 2012 and the destination is Oracle 12 and both are residing in the same system. Now my questions are 
1. What is the best way to setup the initial load? I meant to use some SQL Server utility such as SSIS or use Goldengate's "Direct Bulk load" feature?
2. Though my source DB and destination DB are residing on the same machine, do I still have to use two installations (one for source and other for destination) of the Goldengate for transaction replication?

Answer (score 1):

I used GG direct load for MSSQL initial load; the database was huge and it went fine. The downside of it is that if a failure occurs, then you'll need to truncate the target table ans start the load from the beginning. As for multiple installations, in one environment I have both target and source Oracle databases running on the same machine and using the same installation, so I think you'll be fine with just one.

Look at the link it could be beneficial
http://www.ateam-oracle.com/oracle-goldengate-heterogeneous-database-initial-load-using-oracle-goldengate/